# AWS Javascript SDK CORS error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I'm using the AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser, with S3. In the following code the first call, getSignedUrl works fine but the second one to getObject fails with a CORS error - origin not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Has anyone any idea what obvious, simple and idiotic mistake I'm making?

```
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'AAAAAAAAAAAA', secretAccessKey: 'ZZZZZZZZZ'});
 var s3 = new AWS.S3();
 var params = {Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: 'path/to/this/file.json'};

//this works...
 var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
 console.log(url);

//this doesn't...
 var obj = s3.getObject(params, function (error, data) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error); // an error occurred
 } else {
    console.log(data); // request succeeded
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem came from the S3 CORS setup which had defaulted to allowedheaders = Authorized. Replacing it with * did the trick. It's caused by S3 complaining that it's not receiving an Authorized request.

Answer (score 0):

That would be your browser saying that, due to [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), it can't make requests to S3.

You can [enable CORS on your bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) to work around that.

The getSignedUrl call works fine because that is done totally "offline" by the SDK (there is no such call in S3 API).

Comment: It seems to be an authentication issue. When I set the bucket CORS policy to 
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> 
it works but with 
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader> 
it fails. 
Also, the getSignedUrl call fails if the accessKeyId or secretAccessKey are wrong.

Comment: And there is in fact such a call in the S3 API!